# How to create a custom Tab Activity in Android?

Tags: android, tabs

I`m Trying to create a custom Tab Activity but I found default tab activity.
In that I want to change the indicator color to red but unfortunately nothing happens.
Please Help and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried.

Comment: `TabActivity Deprecated` . Too old question . What you tried so far

Comment: you can follow this -
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 classes:

**MyTabs.java**

```
public class MyTabs extends TabLayout {
    String text;
    public MyTabs(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyTabs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyTabs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTabTextColors(int normalColor, int selectedColor) {
        super.setTabTextColors(normalColor, selectedColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        super.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(@NonNull Tab tab) {
        super.addTab(tab);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Tab newTab() {
        return super.newTab();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSmoothScrollingEnabled(boolean smoothScrollingEnabled) {
        super.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(smoothScrollingEnabled);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTabMode(int mode) {
        super.setTabMode(mode);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <com.mypackage.here.MyTabs
        android:id="@+id/mytabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Inside **MainActivity.java**

```
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    MyTabs tabs;
    TabLayout.Tab latestTab;
    TabLayout.Tab allVideosTab;


    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    //Tab layout
    tabs = (MyTabs) findViewById(R.id.mytabs);
    tabs.setTabTextColors(Color.LTGRAY, Color.WHITE);
    tabs.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);
    tabs.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
    tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
    latestTab = tabs.newTab();
    allVideosTab = tabs.newTab();

    //ADD TABS IN REVERSE ORDER OF APPEARANCE
    tabs.addTab(allVideosTab);
    tabs.addTab(latestTab);

    //*********ADD ALL tabs above this*/
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    //Manipulate tabs here
    latestTab.setText("Latest");
    allVideosTab.setText("All Videos");
```